# WinForms UI design advice for list of custom controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

We need a "dashboard" view for a trading application on a C# .Net WinForms application.

Currently the application pops up additional forms with price charts for each symbol (MSFT, GOOG, EUR/USD) for which the user has defined automated trading rules.  But some users want to trade dozens or hundreds of symbols simultaneously. The application handles this performance-wise but this creates far too many separate charts on the desktop.

So the need is for a form with a list of information and controls for each of the symbols.

Please offer advice on selecting which controls to use for this.

Okay so here's some requirements:

1. The list needs to be scrollable.
2. On Each Row:
   a) a button to maximize/minimize the chart for that symbol.
   b) a button to pause or resume trading on a symbol as well as show current status.
   c) A few columns of information like symbol, equity, position.
3. Future version: Rows sortable by the information columns.
4. Future version: Make each row "explandable" maybe with a plus/minus sign to
   show additional detail like list of active orders or perhaps a mini "inline" chart
   rather than separate popup.
5. One or more rows will be "portfolio" rows with similar columns to display combined
   equity for its nested symbols and portfolios.
6. We need to implement this as quickly as possible so this rules out designing custom
   controls (at least in this version)--So we want to use only the .Net standard controls.
7. We want to avoid 3rd party solutions unless it's open source.

Trickiest design question:

How to represent the relationships between the strategies and portfolios.
   These relationships can be sophisticated with nested portfolios and a single portfolios 
   instance can be assigned to multiple parent portfolios. Note. The user can't
   alter these relationship at run time...but it will be nice to represent this
   visually. Can that be integrated into this control--like a tree view?  The problem
   is that a single portfolio or symbol can be nested inside multiple other portfolios.
   So that doesn't seem to make sense for a tree view.

Another idea will be to pop up separate list views for each portfolio--yuck.

The best will be some clever idea to represent the relationships visually on the
   same dashboard. Maybe not in this first version but perhaps a custom drawing
   control that actually shows a column per portfolio with a vertical line showing
   symbols or portfolio contained with tick marks? We'd like a simple yet
   elegant solution.

The plan is to get something up and working with the minimum needs but also some forethought into how to get the portfolio relationship and other features in a next version w/o rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: Just a thought - WPF/silverlight is very good for what you want to do... Can you host a webbrowser control in your winforms app to show a silverlight app on a webpage or use an elementhost to host a wpf control?

Comment: My struggle is that while very skilled with all things web and back end on the server, I'm all thumbs at working with desktop GUI. So what you describe above sounds "hard" to me with a lot of learning curve. Right now, I've gotten relatively comfortable with WinForms but so far only read a book about WPF and not quite ready due to go that route due to business deadlines.

Comment: Hmmm... What you want to do is doable but pretty advanced as far as Winforms UI devlopment goes. It is all so much easier using WPF.  If deadlines are your constraint - How about investing in pre-built RAD controls such as those provided by devexpress or telarik?

Comment: @Jay Well it seems the hard part will be converting the existing app over from WinForms or else trying to integrate the old code with the new WPF code. IT seems easier to put something together with Forms for now. We do have future plans for upgrading the whole GUI to WPF at a later date.

Comment: @ Wayne - I think you may have misunderstood - third party controls are available from Devexpress or Telarik for Winform applications as well as WPF or Silverlight; These will will allow you do do fancy charts and graphs in a winforms application without a huge learning curve and should work right out of the box. Best of luck anyway!

Comment: @Jay Thanks. Trying to stick with WinForms at the moment. I want to knock this out in 1 day. I'm sure getting setup and learning WPF (since I never did it before) will take longer than that.

Comment: @Jay I'm looking into WPF/SilverLight control in spite of myself. It appears that once I figure it out, it will, indeed be the best way to do this. I'll try a WPF/Silverlight hello world and go from there. If I do it this way, I'll approve your answer. Thanks for pushing what looks like it might turn out to be a great idea.

Comment: Would collapsible panels in a FlowLayoutPanel give you the basics of what you want? There is an implementation of a collapsible panel here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53318/C-Custom-Control-Featuring-a-Collapsible-Panel I am sure there are lots more around.

Comment: @Mark Interesting idea. It seems all information must be visible in each list of information unless the list gets very long. In that case, we found a control that has builtin ability to sort. So we'll have the list sortable by columns for the user to keep the most important at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

if you know winform better then I think you can try to use some tab control ,nested tab control,resizable panel,etc for your dashboard with backgrounds workers thread control .

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I see why you suggest "tabs". But the requirement of this is to have all the possible summary information visible at the same time. And thus the term "dashboard" so it's possible to monitor the trading with an "overview" and then click to zoom in. And the controls on each tab will be hidden until that tab is selected, right? I'm considering a simple list of controls right now w/o the sortable columns or showing portfolio relationships.